# How to access Map Fields in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following list stored in a variable:

```dart
widget.item.comments = [{comment: comment text, username: username, commentID: 1}];
```

And I'd like to update the `comment` field in a function.

I tried to the following and I know that the `id` is correct:

```dart
final comment = widget.item.comments.firstWhere((item) => item.commentID == id);
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'commentID'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that Dart maps are not accessed like JavaScript maps, i.e. map fields are not added as getters or properties of objects.

Instead, [`Map` overrides operators](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Map-class.html#operators). This means that you will want to use *square brackets* to access your map fields:

```dart
final commentID = item['commentID'];

// Applying this to your example:
final comment = widget.item.comments.firstWhere((item) => item['commentID'] == id);
```

Comment: Thank you! That indeed did the trick. I'll accept the answer in few minutes when it's possible :).